# HTML 5 Video not playing from my MVC website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, html5-video

I have a simple `MVC` action that returns a `FilePathResult` pointing to a video. For some reason `HTML5` video (using `js-video.js`) is not playing the video. If I change the URL to a URL I know works, the video plays fine. So it must be to do with the way I serve the file.

If I browse to the URL in the browser, the video downloads and then plays fine.

The video is `.mp4` with a returned MIME type of `video/mp4`.

I am using `Video Studio 2012`, `.NET 4`, `IIS 8 Express` and `Windows 7 x64 Home Premium`.

Here is my respective code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "File_Read")]
public FileResult Get(int? id)
{
    try
    {
        if (id == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("id");

        var fileRepo = FileRepositoryFactory.Repository;

        var file = fileRepo.GetById(id.Value);
        if (file == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException(String.Format("Failed to find file with id: {0}", id));

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file.FilePath))
        {
            return this.File(file.Data, file.MIMEType, file.FileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return this.File(file.FilePath, file.MIMEType, file.FileName);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return this.File("failed.txt", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of what `Chrome` returns:

[image: Network]

[image: File get request]

[image: Failed mp4 request]

[image: Failed mp4 request details]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML5 `Video` tage requires support for **[Range Requests](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)**.

In case of static file this support is provided internally by the server, but in case of *ASP.NET MVC* action it needs to be implemented at `ActionResult` level.

The article [Range Requests in ASP.NET MVC – RangeFileResult](http://tpeczek.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/range-requests-in-aspnet-mvc.html) describes in details how to create an ASP.NET MVC `ActionResult` with *Range Request* support. There is also a sample application which is using *VideoJS* available here: [VideoJS in ASP.NET MVC](http://tpeczek.codeplex.com/releases/view/74711)

Comment: Thanks for that. I have it working with mp3 files, but my mp4 doesn't work. I have added the screen shots with the error information in my main post.

Comment: @rhughes The content-length you have marked is correct because the request has the `Range: bytes=518758-518758` header (the browser is asking for one byte). There are some issue with playing mp4 files on Chrome (unsupported encodings etc.) just google to find some. I suggest to test your mp4 file in another browser, and test an mp4 which is known to be working in Chrome (this one should be good - http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw/upload/bunny.mp4 first test it from this location than download and use in your app). Also make sure there are proper codes in your markup of HTML5 video/source.

Comment: I have tried the bunny video and it works fine in IE 9, but not in Chrome. Do you know why this is?

Comment: @rhughes From what I know Chrome doesn't support some of encodings which can be used for mp4 files, you can find a lot of threads regarding this when you google `'chrome mp4 issue'`. I'm affraid that I'm not a guru in video encoding subject (I'm not even sure if this is a subject for StackOverflow) but your test confirms that the ASP.NET MVC part works correctly and the issue is in Chrome. I suggest you ask a separate question regarding the Chrome issue in place where you can find some Chrome specialists.

Comment: That makes sense. Google has thrown up some interesting comments. Thank for your help!

Comment: @tpeczek, I am encountering problems with RangeFileResult and this error: "server cannot set status after http headers have been sent".

When playing videos in Chrome, using RangeFileResult, the video frequently dissappears and displays the message 'Video not properly encoded', I think this may be related to the previous error message I mention, any ideas?

Comment: @Tyler I would need to know a lot more about your project in order to be able to say anything. Please feel free to contact me directly via email (available in my profile).

Comment: @tpeczek I have posted a question on Stack because it is easier to read, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336690/error-with-html5-video-in-chrome-using-rangefilepathresult, hope you don't mind